# Tag popup is obscured on the Tour page

Tags: bug, tags, design, popups, tour

On the [Tour page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour) the popup for tags on demo questions is partially obscured by the frame border:

> [image]

Comment: The bug is that the tag popup is active at all, it shouldn't be. It's just a sample question, e.g. you also can't and shouldn't vote on it from the tour page. I honestly can't grasp why they didn't simply post screenshot. Would have saved tons of bugs.